# An obvious prior art… mobile phone

Tags: prior-art, claims, mobile-phone, obviousness, us8964397

Shouldn't an obvious prior art of this claim be any smart phone / mobile phone with video screen, speaker and a port which load images for display?

> What is claimed is:
>
> 1. An electronic media production system comprising:
>
>    modules, each including: a presentation system including one or more of a speaker and a video screen; a port; and one or more connectors; and
>
>    actuators, each actuator, in use, being coupled without soldering to a respective connector,
>
>    wherein, in use, the presentation system of each module operates in response to the actuator or actuators coupled to said each module, the presentation system:
>
>    if the presentation system includes the speaker, producing sounds derived from data obtained via the port; and
>
>    if the presentation system includes the video screen, displaying images derived from data obtained via the port.

In reference to the patent: [US8964397](https://www.google.com/patents/US8964397)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether or not the invention is novel or non-obvious, but from [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) it seems the point of differentiation over the prior art the Examiner found was in the actuator and in particular how the actuator was attached to the respective connector.